# After stripping unwanted tags, what else should I do to text input?

Tags: php, xhtml, string, filter, tags

In a PHP script I'm accepting input from the user from a `textarea` and want to allow a few basic tags. So when I output the string I'm using -

```
echo strip_tags($content, '<b><i><ul><ol><li>');
```

Now normally I would use `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` but that would strip all tags and I would use `html_entities()` but that would prevent the tags I'm passing through from displaying as they should.

So what else do I need to strip or encode and how do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can rely on `strip_tags()` for security purposes - from http://php.net/strip_tags:

> This function does not modify any
>   attributes on the tags that you allow
>   using allowable_tags , including the
>   style and onmouseover attributes that
>   a mischievous user may abuse when
>   posting text that will be shown to
>   other users.

It might be better to look at something like [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) or [PEAR HTML_Safe](http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_Safe), which should be able to do exactly what you want.

Comment: I recommend the HTML Purifier too.

Answer (score 1):

There are some attributes you probably wish to remove as well such as `style`. You may also want remove event handlers like `onMouseOver` and `onClick`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I've had success with Cal Henderson's [lib_filter](http://code.iamcal.com/php/lib_filter/lib_filter.phps) in the past, which is a very good lightweight PHP4/5 library for filtering tags and attributes from input. You can specify the allowed tags/attributes via the 'allowed' member variable e.g. the following code sanitizes embed code from sites like YouTube/Vimeo/Flickr etc. but strips out everything else:

```
        $lib_filter = new lib_filter();
        $lib_filter->allowed = array(
            'object' => array('width', 'height'),
            'param' => array('name', 'value'),
            'embed' => array('src', 'type', 'allowscriptaccess', 'allowfullscreen', 'width', 'height')
        );
        $video = $lib_filter->go($input);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your input against the rules mentioned on the [XSS cheat sheet](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html). Also from a security stand point, it would be best to familiarize yourself with [OWASP Guide to Building Secure Web Applications and Web Services](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Guide_Project)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
echo filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW)
```

very good tutorial :

http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Filtering-Data-with-PHP.html#12

Comment: I would normally use this, but the problem here is that it will strip ALL tags and I want a few to be passed through.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
function stripSingleTags($tags, $string)
{
    foreach( $tags as $tag )
    {
        $string = preg_replace('#</?'.$tag.'[^>]*>#is', '', $string);
    }
    return $string;
}

/*** example usage ***/
$string = '<p>stuff</p><span>more <span class="foo">and even>< more</span> stuff here</span>';

$tags = array('h1', 'span');

echo stripSingleTags($tags, $string);
```

Source: http://www.phpro.org/examples/Strip-Single-Tag.html